# Changing CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey from peripheral

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Is there any way to modify `CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey` from `CBPeripheralManager`? I understand I can get the `CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey` from `CBCentralManager`.

The reason I want to do this is because I want the peripheral to advertise a 10-byte value without resorting to having the central connect to it, discover services, and then reading a characteristic which would contain the 10-byte value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible as of iOS 7. The Manufacturer Data is reserved by Apple and is unmodifiable (at least on non-jailbroken devices). If you were writing the firmware for your own peripheral, this would not be a problem. But since the CoreBluetooth api is a layer above Apple's actual implementation of the iOS ble firmware, we face the limitations of what they actually expose. You may consider advertising you own custom service and displaying the same value you would have put in the manufacturer data, however.

Comment: would I be able to retrieve this custom service from the peripheral (iOS device) without having to connect to it?

Comment: Yes, it would be in the advertisement data seen when a device is discovered. However, there are limitations on advertising in the background vs. foreground. Check out the peripheralManager docs for more details https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/Reference/CBPeripheralManager.html

Comment: OH - the local name. yes im aware of this but I require peripherals to advertise in the background as well... feeling very limited with the current iOS SDK